# Twilio 502 Error From Following Tutorial on AWS Server

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZeCz_QOoXw) on my AWS Ubuntu instance and when I attempted to text the number Twilio had given me ngrok reported a 502 Error. Is it possible that I need to open a port inside of the security details for the instance?

Comment: Are you using ngrok on an AWS instance?